# Prevent factory reset after 10 wrong password attempts on LG G3

Tags: factory-reset, lg-g3

My LG G3 does a factory reset every time you get the password wrong 10 times. It has happened twice and I have lost everything that wasn't backed up along with at least half an hour to redo everything. Is there a way to stop this, without rooting it?

Comment: Related forum posts ([1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-lg-g3/help/how-to-disable-wrong-password-factory-t2828400), [2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/10-password-passcode-attempts-factory-t2830996)), but no solution yet.